# TypeScript and Node and importing

Tags: node.js, import, typescript

I'm trying to use **TypeScript** inside **Node.js** with `typescript-require`. So I init it like:

```
// index.js, line 1.
require("typescript-require")({ "nodeLib": true });
```

And so I load the `Main.ts` file. Like it:

```
// index.js, line 2.
require("Main.ts").init();
```

So I have a `Dictionary` interface:

```
// Main.ts, line 8.
interface Dictionary<TValue> {
    [index: string]: TValue;
}
```

When I put this code directly on `Main.ts` it run fine, like it:

```
// Main.ts, line 12.
var list: Dictionary<number> = {};
```

But I like to separate the `Dictionary` from `Main`. To allow others files use this interface without duplicate it. **And here starts my problem.** I don't know how I can do that. I tried a lot things, like use `reference` and `import require`, and I receive errors from all methods.

```
/// Without any import, I get an obvious error; or,
/// <reference path="Dictionary" />; or,
/// <reference path="Dictionary.ts" />; or,
/// <reference path="./Dictionary.ts" />; or,
import Dictionary = require("Dictionary");
>> Main.ts(6,18): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Dictionary'.

import Dictionary = require("Dictionary.ts");
>> Main.ts(1,29): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Dictionary'.
>> Main.ts(6,18): error TS2315: Type 'any' is not generic.
```

In all cases, seems that `Main.ts` doesn't include the file correctly, so I can't reuse that. So I'm forgetting something?

Answer (score 0):

Before I post it I found the solution. I was trying export interface on file `Dictionary.ts` like it:

```
export interface ... { ... }
```

But I need `export =` it. Like:

```
interface Name { ... }
export = Name;
```